# SQL statement to count all rows that changed from previous day for 'Column_a'

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I am looking for a SQL query to count all rows that changed from the previous day for 'column_a'. The table has one date column 'historyDate'.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one row per day, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(column_a) over (order by historydate) as prev_column_a
      from t
     ) t
where prev_column_a <> column_a;
```

Note:  This assumes that `column_a` is never `NULL`.  The logic can be tweaked to handle this, but it gets a bit more complicated.